# Oracle SQL- Add Column from second table if conditions for that row are met

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, join, select

I would like to bring in column C from table 2 if columns A and B in table 1 the row of table 2 that match columns A and B.

Table 1

```
Column A         Column B
ABC123           XX470000
```

Table 2

```
Column A            Column  B              Column  C
ABC123,EFG123       XX470000,XX560000      Winner
```

Query:

```
Select * From
(
Select * From Table 1 
) T1.
(
Select * From Table 2 
) T2.

where T1.ColumnA in s2.ColumnA 
and T1.ColumnB in s2.ColumnB 
;
```

I have tried "like", "in" and "=" statements to match up the different tables. 
There are also thousands of rows where I would need this.

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to check for the presence each value in the csv list, then you can use the following join conditions:

```
select t1.*, t2.columnC
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
    on  ',' || t2.columna || ',' like '%,' || t1.columna || ',%' 
    and ',' || t2.columnb || ',' like '%,' || t1.columnb || ',%'
```

However, you should really fix your schema and store each value of the csv string on a separate table row (possibly using a bridge table). Storing delimited values in a table somehow defeats the purpose of a relational database. Recommended related reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function within a
`SELECT .. FROM .. CONNECT BY level <= ...` type query with `'[^,]+'` to split the `ColumnA` 
 values of the `Table2` into substrings seperated by commas, and then join with the other tables' `ColumnA` values in the matching condition in order to get the  exact matches for those substrings :

```
SELECT t1.ColumnA, t2.ColumnC
  FROM
  (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t2.ColumnA,'[^,]+',1,level) AS ColumnA, ColumnC
      FROM Table2 t2
   CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(t2.ColumnA,',') + 1
      AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
  ) t2
  JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e897530c60f9165c149ba661ffce96b8)</kbd>

Comment: Exactly, you're right @GMB . I've changed the style.